# Android simple methods not working?

Tags: java, android, methods

I have a spinner where the user can select something. When they do, it calls `switchCat()` which then calls `chooseView()` and based on the `int` passed will do something different. In this case it loads a different set of array strings.

However, whenever I run it, I will ONLY see the strings from `R.array.array0`, so the first `if` in `chooseView()`. `csArray` is set nowhere else. I am calling `chooseView()` onCreate.

I am a novice. Thank you!

**Spinner item selected**

```
@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(int itemPosition, long itemId) {
    if (synthetic) {
        synthetic = false;
        return true;
    }
    switchCat(itemPosition);
    return true;
}
```

**switchCat();**

```
public void switchCat(int i) { 
    if(i == 0) {
     chooseView(0);
    }
    else if(i == 1) {
     chooseView(1);
    }
}
```

**chooseView()**

```
public void chooseView(int i) {
    if(i == 0) {
        CharSequence[] csArray = getResources().getTextArray(R.array.array0);

        for (CharSequence s : csArray) {
            mArrayList.add(s);

        }
    }
    if(i == 1) {
        CharSequence[] csArray = getResources().getTextArray(R.array.array1);

        for (CharSequence s : csArray) {
            mArrayList.add(s);

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you are adding items to your `ArrayList`. Are you sure you don't mean to get rid of old ones as well prior to adding? If you don't, they will remain in the list when `chooseView()` is called. In `chooseView()`, simply call `mArrayList.clear()` before your `if` statements. This, of course, assumes that your `ListView` is dependent on `mArrayList`.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you  run first time it will give correct output,another time you arraylist will add the values with previous one,so every time you want's to clear the arraylist for get a correct output.

```
public void switchCat(int i) { 
    myArrayList.clear();
    if(i == 0) {
     chooseView(0);
    }
    else if(i == 1) {
     chooseView(1);
    }
}
```